# Value of select list (dropdown) not shown just the (unwanted) indexnumbers

Tags: php, html, smarty

I know questions like this are asked before, but i can't find the correct answer for my question.

Within a HTML form i have a select list (dropdown) named "custnames" which is filled from a database (within PHP).

The HTML page is saved as a tpl file because i work with Smarty.

All the values (custnames) are shown correctly in the list when i click the dropdown select box.

When i click the submit button i can't get the chosen name from the select list into the $_POST["custnames"]. 
The only thing the $_POST["custnames"] has is the index number from the chosen option from the select list.

How can i get the chosen name from the dropdownlist into the $_POST["custnames"] instead of the index number of that name.

All other fields have also Smarty tags and work fine with their respective $_POST[]

I searched the web for a long time now and tried many things but nothing works so far.

I use the same code like the example wich comes from a studybook about Smarty.
HTML(Smarty) code:

```
<td colspan="2">
    <select name="custnames" class="gewonetekst" id="custnames">
        {html_options options=$custnames selected=$cust}
    </select>
</td>
```

The list is filled from a database wich is working fine.

PHP code:

```
$klt_array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $klt_array[] = $row[name]
}

$m_objSmarty->assign('custnames', $klt_array);
```

When i click on the selectlist i see all the names correctly in the select (dropdown) list.

All other (Smarty) fields work fine with their respectiv $_POST[] exept this one.

T.i.a.

Regards,

Tino, The Netherlands.

Comment: Code please! You can't receive an answer to your problem without showing your code!

Comment: Added code to my question

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't set  "value" attribute of custnames option tags with the proper value.

Check if they are defined as

```
<option value="My_custname_1">My_custname_1</option>
```

Surely not. You should put the same tag inside option tags and value attribute in your smarty template if you want to receive the same as shown